# How to import dependencies in reactjs class?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, webpack

I created a react jsx file (index.jsx) as shown below. The first line is used to import jquery library in our class.

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import './main.css';
import './component';
import Search from './search/search'
```

when I started the webpack-dev-server, I got below error:

```
index.jsx Line 1: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import $ from 'jquery';
| import React from 'react';
| import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

I have added the jquery and react dependencies on my package.json file. I wonder what I missed here.

Comment: Are you using a compiler such as babel? Can u post your webpack.config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is tagged as React, but I don't see it. If you want to use React, do something like:

HelloWorld.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';

var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <h1> Hello World! </h1>
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='content'/>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you don't want to use React, please post your other code so we can see how everything couples together, and where things go wrong.

Comment: I do want to use react but I got the error before importing react. Actually, I tried your code but got this error: "index.jsx Line 1: Unexpected token You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type." I have changed the post to include this error.

Answer (score 0):

juste do :

```
var $ = require("query");
        module.exports = { 
          function(){

           var element = document.createElement('h1');

           element.innerHTML = 'Hello world';

           return element;
         }
    }
```

another syntaxe can be :

```
var $ = require("query");
    module.exports = { 
              myFunction : function(){

               var element = document.createElement('h1');

               element.innerHTML = 'Hello world';

               return element;
             }
        }
```

Comment: I want to import jquery can other libraries, where should I place the import code?

Comment: at the top  of module export like you did, can be : var $ = require("query");